# Android grant permission error

Tags: android, permissions, adb, robotium

I got this error when i was going to grant CHANGE_CONFIGURATION permission to my application:(is Windows platform)

CMD command line error is below:

> /$ pm grant packageName android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION >
>
> operation not allowed: java.lang.SecurityException: Package packageName has not requested permission android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION

Anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. You shouldn't take screenshots of your code. It's possible to copy them out of the terminal. Don't be lazy, write them directly into the question.

Comment: @Smittey Thanks. I edited my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you requested `CHANGE_CONFIGURATION` in your Manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION">
```

Which device and version of Android are you using? I've tested the `pm grant` command on a Nexus 6 using Android 6 (MRA58N), it worked.

Comment: Operation not allowed: java.lang.SecurityException: Package com.google.android.gms has not requested permission android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION

Comment: Which device and version of Android are you using?

Comment: It's a amlogic setup box, via Android 4.4.2

Answer (score 0):

You have to request the permission to be granted.

inside OnCreate method of your main activity:

```
// New permissions model test
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
{
    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        String [] permissions = new String[1];
        permissions[0] = Manifest.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION;

        requestPermissions(permissions, 7001);
    }
}
```

And override this in your activity:

```
@Override public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults)
{
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if(grantResults[0] == 0)    // Permission was granted
        yourJob.start();    
}
```

Of course, declare it in the manifest.xml as well

Comment: But i only have apk file.What i am currently working on is automated-tests code.There are no onCreate method. What should i do?

Comment: `CHANGE_CONFIGURATION` is a `signature|privileged|development` permission, it will not be granted to an application using `requestPermissions()`.